# Run Site in xx Second in CMD

Tags: http, cmd

Can you help me in **CMD**. i want to make batch file,like this:

when opening this file it must open *one web-site* and in some second**(for example in 10 sec)** it must open *the second web-site* and *the third* and *so and so*   .

Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve by this script?

If you're doing load testing, there are plenty useful tools out there...
Take a look at [this list](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) for example.

If you must do it in a batch file, what is your environment? Windows, I assume? Can you run Powershell or Windows Scripting Host files? Using these, you can fairly easily script your browser to open a website, delay for `x` seconds, and open another website.

There is some code here to open a website using WSH:

http://www.vistax64.com/vb-script/258346-how-script-ie-open-certain-webpage-prompted-user-pass.html

Code from above website:

```
Dim aLinks(2)
aLinks(0) = "http://localhost"
aLinks(1) = "http://otherhost"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ', "oIE_")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.FullScreen = False

'open a new window
oIE.Navigate2 aLinks(0)
Do While oIE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 50
Loop

WScript.Sleep 2000
For J = Lbound(aLinks) To Ubound(aLinks)
  oIE.Navigate2 aLinks(J), navOpenInBackgroundTab 'navOpenInNewTab '
  Do While oIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
  Loop
  WScript.Sleep 3000
Next

WshShell.SendKeys "^{TAB}" 'go to the 2nd tab
WScript.Sleep 100
on error goto 0
```

Answer (score 1):

- For opening a Web site, you can call `IExplore.exe` (or whatever browser is available) with the URL in the command line, and it will.
- The trickier part is inserting a 10s delay without using specialized utilities. Believe it or not, Microsoft's recommended procedure for this is to `ping` a non-existent site with a timeout (given by option `-w`) of 10 seconds.

Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" http://my.site/1.html
ping -n1 -w10 10.9.8.7
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" http://my.site/2.html
ping -n1 -w10 10.9.8.7
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" http://my.site/3.html
ping -n1 -w10 10.9.8.7
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Iexplore.exe" http://my.site/4.html
ping -n1 -w10 10.9.8.7
```

Comment: What, that's crazy... but a bit funny at the same time :) I'm talking about the delay by ping here...

Comment: +1 A bit hardcoded and difficult to maintain, but answers the question perfectly :)

Comment: Oh wait, shouldn't the browsers close afterwards? If you have 1000 websites to test, you should make sure that you have set IE to reuse existing windows, or you'll have a shitstorm of IE instances running...

Comment: If this were testing, I think this wouldn't be a batch file. You can't test whether the site exists anyway when just opening a browser.

Comment: Maybe it's for load testing? So the url list consists of multiple urls for the same site... otherwise I can't really think of a legitimate use of such a script?

Comment: Hey, wait a minute. Shouldn't we be providing the answers, not the questions?

Comment: Well, "What the hell are you trying with that?" isn't an uncommon question around here :-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, opening a browser can work for opening a web page. Rather than hard-coding the browser, you can simply use `start`:

```
start "" "http://my/url"
```

To wait 10 seconds you can also ping yourself 11 times:

```
ping localhost -n 11 >nul 2>&1
```

or, starting with Windows Vista you can use `timeout`:

```
timeout /T 10 /NOBREAK >nul
```

So you can cobble together something like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

set TIMEOUT=10

set WEBPAGE0=http://google.com
set WEBPAGE1=http://stackoverflow.com
set WEBPAGE2=http://en.wikipedia.org
set WEBPAGE3=...  extend as needed

set N=0
set /a X=TIMEOUT+1
:loop
if not defined WEBPAGE%N% goto :eof
start "" "!WEBPAGE%N%!"
ping localhost -n %X% >nul 2>&1
goto loop
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution with timeout, seems so much better than pinging :)

Comment: So it only took Microsoft 25 years to develop the equivalent of the `sleep` command? Can't wait to see what the next 25 years will bring!

Comment: Oh, you always had one with `ping` :-). Also remember that Windows is not UNIX and not necessarily the same rules need to apply. There is simply no need to have a command-line wrapper around every single API function. At least for 99 % of users. Besides, more powerful capabilities are present in both WSH and PowerShell, the latter of which I find not only on par but actually better than UNIX-like command-line environments.

Comment: Heh, I'm more than 2x your age and remember when the Norton Utilities included 4DOS and other programs to help make a batch environment useful: Waiting, single-char input, text formatting, various conversions... I agree that PowerShell is good stuff but it was an awfully long time coming.

Comment: Ah well, I never really liked 4DOS and 4NT somehow. But back when I tried them I wasn't much of a command-line user. But I *do* remember the Batch Enhancer (BE), and yes, it was handy :-). But I actually do like `cmd`, somehow. It's relaxing to try to solve problems in such a language. Maybe I'm just weird :-)